# Twitter Bootstrap: Performance comparison between Data Attribute and Programmatic APIs?

Tags: javascript, dom, twitter-bootstrap

According [to this](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html), the data-attribute API isn't always the most performant.
Have you noticed significant improvements by switching from data-attribute to programmatic api ?

Comment: I think it's more a matter of good practice. And since it's client side the optimization is minimum for the average user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').off('.data-api');
});
```

on javascript.html (where all the javascript plugin are called) downloaded here : https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/zipball/master

**data-api off:**

there's 16026 calls and it takes 226.998ms

[image: benchmark twitter bootstrap data-api off]

**data-api on (original file):**

same number of calls and it takes approximately the same time

[image]

**Conclusion**

The difference is marginal despite the page containing all the twitter bootstrap jquery plugins.

I think it's definitely more a matter of good practice than a big optimisation in term of performance.

Comment: What did you measure exactly? I suspect the bootstrapping code (i.e attaching all the delegated event handlers to the document) overhead is minimal compared to the runtime cost of checking whether the event target applies as you click, mousedown, etc; Not sure how fast JQuery runs that filtering code.